# CDI postconstruct initializing field

Tags: multithreading, cdi, postconstruct

Does anyone know whether the initialization of instance fields within a method annotated with PostConstruct is considered to be thread safe? I am not quite sure if i have to make my fields of my ApplicationScoped bean volatile or not so other threads can really see the values...

Thanks for any hints or answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a direct reference to the spec that absolutely guarantees this, but `@PostConstruct` should be thread safe.

The CDI runtime is fully in charge of creating beans and will only create one instance for a given scope. `@PostConstruct` runs before the bean is accessible in such a scope or via injection.

Comment: Thanks man, would be even better if you could tell me for sure, since from a JMM perspective i think i would have to make them volatile, if there were no memory barriers.

Comment: You would think, but likely your other threads won't even get a reference to the instance before CDI has initialized the bean. In case of concurrent requests for a bean, I'm pretty sure all threads are stuck on the hypothetical `beanManager.getBean(...)` call.

Comment: Thanks, that's of course the only behavior that makes sense, but I wanted to know it for sure without having to read the spec. ;)